# Return value is always undefined - AWS.SES example running in an Express app

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using some code from an AWS example to send an email via SES, inside an Express app. The email works great, but I want to be able to change the response to the browser based on the success or failure of sending the email.

But the function that sends the email always returns undefined, I think because the calling function is not awaiting the result properly.

In the express app:

```
app.post('/api/sendEmail', sendEmail);

async function sendEmail(request, response){
    //console.dir(request.body);
    await emailer(request.body)
    .then(result => console.log(result));
    //should base response on result
    response.json(('{"status": "success"}'));
}
```

Then I have another file with the emailer function in it, loaded as `emailer`.

```
module.exports = async function sendEmailFunction(data) {
         console.log('send email function');
         let email = new AWS.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'}).sendEmail(createEmailParams(buildEmail(data))).promise();
         email.then(
             function(res) {
               console.log(res.MessageId); // works
               return res.MessageId;       // undefined
             }).catch(
               function(err) {
               console.error('problems', err, err.stack);
               return `Error! ${err}, ${err.stack}`;
             });
}
```

in the console I always get:

```
send email function
undefined
0101017865c6f27b-955661fb-af47-4490-8eb6-7b59a0ec3414-000000
```

the guid thing is the console log of res.MessageId (email was successful). Undefined is the console log in the first function logging the result. I can see undefined show slightly before the messageid so I think the sendEmail function is not waiting for the emailer to complete.

Fairly sure the functions in the sendEmail function `createEmailParams(buildEmail(data)` aren't the problem, if I delete them then I still get undefined returned instead of the error message.

Comment: `sendEmailFunction` never returns anything, so you get the standard return value for Javascript functions, which is `undefined`.

Comment: that was not obvious to me at all, it is all within the same function the way I look at it. Now I think I can see how the `function(res)` is its own thing and it is returning back to the parent function not to my other function that called the parent. I think if I had written out nested functions like this that were not promises I would have known that the inner function was just returning to the parent and not to the one that called the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On face value it doesn't look like you're returning the promise to be awaited up stream of sendEmailFunction, nor is it being awaited in the function itself. Consider awaiting the response and returning it in sendEmailFunction, or returning the email promise and letting the upstream function await it and tease out the value it's looking for.

For example:

```
module.exports = async function sendEmailFunction(data) {
     console.log('send email function');
     let email = new AWS.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'}).sendEmail(createEmailParams(buildEmail(data))).promise();
     let response = await email.then(
         function(res) {
           console.log(res.MessageId); // works
           return res.MessageId;       // undefined
         }).catch(
           function(err) {
           console.error('problems', err, err.stack);
           return `Error! ${err}, ${err.stack}`;
         });
     return response; }
```

Comment: ahhh. Got it. Initially I just saw that you added a return at the bottom and added that, which I could get a test value from, but I had not noticed that in the middle you did `let repsonse = await ..`. Now I see how yours works. Thanks so much, spent several hours trying different things.